# Regional setting confusion regarding date format from PostgreSQL

Tags: delphi, postgresql, delphi-7, regional-settings

I'm working on an application that requires the following regional settings (Delphi 7 and PostgreSQL 9.0):

```
   1. DateSeparator:='/';
   2. TimeSeparator:=':';
   3. ThousandSeparator:=',';
   4. DecimalSeparator:='.';
   5. ShortDateFormat:='MM/dd/yy';
   6. ShortTimeFormat:='hh:mm:ss';
```

I need to change the regional setting only for my application and not system wide.

In OnCreate of the form I set the above separators, and 
my current system separators are:

```
   1. DateSeparator='|';
   2. TimeSeparator='|';
   3. ThousandSeparator='|';
   4. DecimalSeparator='|';
```

(This is for the test purpose.)

Now in Postgres I have a table from where I get dates to display in my application but somehow the dateseparator doesn't seem to work (as seen in label1)!

[image]

Check the image.

[image]

I fire a query to get the dates from the table

```
                    Label1.Caption:=(Fields(1).Text);
                    Label2.Caption:=datetostr(Fields(1).Data) ;
```

The query is

```
 select min(dat), max(dat) from diary where survey in (2008401) and event not in ('E','C','R') and region=6100;
```

now the same date if I take as .data differ in the date separator from .text dateseparator
why this is happening?

Why are the regional settings not applied to `label1.caption` (as shown in the image)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i found on one site
[enter link description here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/8-postgresql-date-and-time-function-examples/)
for getting the appropriate format all i had to do was get the fire the query as
     `select to_char(min(dat),'mm/dd/yy'), to_char(min(dat),'mm/dd/yy') 
     from diary 
     where survey in (2008401) and 
     event not in ('E','C','R') and region=6100;`

This gave me the proper result in the format i wanted

Comment: +1 Glad to see you got it sorted out, and thanks for posting the solution for others in the future who have the same sort of problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

`DateToStr` uses `ShortDateFormat` as the output format. You didn't change that from the `MM/dd/yy` set initially; you only changed the `DateSeparator`.

I'm confused though, about why you'd want to use `(Fields(1).Text)` (is that right? Parentheses instead of [] for the Fields subscript?).

If the DB is configured to use `|` as the date separator, as it appears it is from your screen image, why are you using `DateToStr`? It appears that `.Text` is getting the information in the format you're looking to obtain.

Comment: hey
i want to know why the dateseparator has a different effect on label1.caption and label2.caption?<br/><br/>
the date separator i want is '/' and not '|'..

Comment: I answered this. `DateToStr` uses `ShortDateFormat`, which you didn't change. Please read my answer again - the effect is different because you used two different ways to work with the values. You need to either set both ways (`ShortDateFormat` and `DateSeparator`) to be compatible, or just use one of them and be consistent in doing so. I don't know what else you're looking for here.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply :)<br/>

this is my code to display in the label caption<br/>
     DateSeparator:='/';
                      ShortDateFormat:='MM/dd/yy';
                      label1.caption:=Fields(1).Text   <br/>
the result is  03|18|08 <br/> but i want it as 03/18/08